# How to locate apps on android device and display in listview?

Tags: android, xml, button, view, sdk

I am currently working on a project just to uninstall apps, but i cant seem to find out how to locate the apps install on my phone.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or give me some insight? Your knowledge would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to achieve this

```
 package pack.GetAllInstalledApplications;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class GetAllInstalledApplicationsExample extends Activity {

 public  ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> res = new ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct>(); 
 public ListView list;
 public String app_labels[];

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getPackages();

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);     
        try{
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, app_labels));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Err ++> " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

 }
private ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i);
    }
    return apps;
}

private ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {

    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    try{
        app_labels = new String[packs.size()];
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }                   
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PackageInfoStruct newInfo = new PackageInfoStruct();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);  

        app_labels[i] = newInfo.appname;
    }
    return res; 
}
    }
     /* This class is for storing the data for each application */
     class PackageInfoStruct {
         String appname = "";
         String pname = "";
         String versionName = "";
         int versionCode = 0;
         Drawable icon;  
     }
```

And Simply declare a List view in your XML. this will do the trick.

Comment: do i have to allow any permissions?

Comment: just asking because after it loads the app names and i begin scrolling it force closes the app

Comment: how do you make the listview item open the app is for onclick